# Retrieving json data is too slow from SQL Server in C# API

Tags: c#, json, api, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to retrieve a huge amount of JSON data by transforming 30000 rows of a table to JSON in a SQL Server stored procedure and calling that stored procedure from a C# API as shown below. But it is taking too much time (approx 2 minutes) to get the data.

Stored procedure code is executing in less than 8 seconds, but after getting that data in the API, it is taking more time to return it.

I have googled but not find the answer, does anyone tell me if I missed anything from my code?

C# code

```
    [Function(Name = "dbo.usp_get_Data")]
    [ResultType(typeof(TemplateResponse))]
    private IMultipleResults uspgeTemplateData(string Id,string Code)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), new object[2] { Id,Code});
        return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
    }

    public DownloadResponse DownloadExcelTemplate(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        DownloadResponse responseMessage = new DownloadResponse();
        IMultipleResults sprocResults = uspgeTemplateData(Id,Code);            
        TemplateResponse xlTemplateResponse = sprocResults.GetResult<TemplateResponse>().AsQueryable<TemplateResponse>().FirstOrDefault();
        responseMessage.response = xlTemplateResponse;
        return responseMessage;
    }
```

Comment: are the columns indexed which the SP is querying on, else it will do a full table scan

Comment: The OP appears to be implying the problem is C# consuming that data, @KunalMukherjee, not SQL Server creating said data.

Comment: thanks for the reply @KunalMukherjee.  yes, all the columns are indexed and  SP execution performance is fine and it is taking only 6 seconds of time. but to consume the data in c# API taking more time.

Comment: How large (KB, MB, etc.) is the data set being returned? Is the C# API using, say, over 80% of its RAM while this is running? Is the JSON deeply nested?

Comment: @MattM- Json size is around 500kb and json is not deeply nested